# Sqlite on Cordova with cordova-plugin-sqlite-2 limits to 32 Bit

Tags: android, sqlite, cordova

I wrote a cordova app, using the plugin cordova-plugin-sqlite-2 from npm.

If I insert numbers bigger than 32 Bit, the integer is cut of.
So if I insert this:

```
txn.executeSql("INSERT INTO Test (ID) VALUES (17179869322)",[]));
```

And then select those values again:

```
txn.executeSql("SELECT * FROM Test",[],function(tx,data){console.log(data)});
```

I get this

```
+-----+
| ID  |
+-----+
| 138 |
+-----+
```

To me it seems like the number is truncated, although this should only happen after 8 byte.
Am I doing something wrong here?

I run the app natively on an Android 7 phone.

After some more testing I found, that I can still select the ID in the SQL statement, but the result is still wrong. Very confusing:

```
txn.executeSql("SELECT * FROM Test where ID=17179869322",[],function(tx,data){console.log(data)});
```

also results in

```
+-----+
| ID  |
+-----+
| 138 |
+-----+
```

Note that I did not do any transformations with the results. The number 322 is read directly in the callback function of the sqlite query methon.

All help appreciated.

Comment: Can you get the DB file on to a PC and check exactly what's in it (e.g. using `sqlite3` command-line tool)? `332` is an "odd" truncation... if there was a "32-bit limit/truncation" in the plugin, I'd expect to see `138`. What does `console.log` do? If it's anything more than a simple print to `logcat`, it might be worth checking that's not doing something odd.

Comment: Whops, copy paste error. It actually is 138. Sorry about that, I'll correct the question. Getting the DB file is not that easy, I do not have a rooted phone, so I'll have to use the file transfer plugin. I'll see what I can do, and report.

Comment: If you can't get the DB easily, double-check the printing mechanism. The fact that the `SELECT` works (as in finds a record) suggests that SQLite has stored the full value, but the problem is either in the plugin's callbacks or the printing process.

Comment: So, it actually seems to be a limitation of the plugin. I switched to another implementation of SQlite on cordova, and no longer have the issue. Thanks for your help! If you turn your comment into an answer somehow, I"ll be glad to accept it :)

Comment: Glad you've solved it. Have added a "how to solve this" answer. Also, I've suggested an edit to the title to mention the specific plug-in you used which may help others in the same position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*The problem was solved through suggestions in comments (it was a problem with the plug-in used). In case it helps anyone in the future, here is an expanded version of the thinking behind that process.*

In a situation like this, you have to approach it as a problem of elimination -- carrying out tests to determine which part is at fault. The most obvious candidates are:

- A problem with SQLite handling >32-bit values;
- The Cordova framework as a whole has a problem with >32-bit numbers;
- The specific plug-in you are using has a problem with >32-bit numbers;
- The way you are using Cordova and/or the plug-in is mishandling 32-bit numbers;

Of these, SQLite is the least likely, since it is known to handle >32-bit numbers. Similarly, although I've no personal experience using it, Cordova is likely to be able to handle >32-bit numbers.

To analyse the other options, probably the most useful diagnostic would be to get a copy of the SQLite database after the insertion and use the SQLite command-line to determine whether the correct values have been inserted or not. Unfortunately, this was not possibly/easy in this case.

However, we can see that both the original insert statement (`INSERT INTO Test (ID) VALUES (17179869322)`) and the targeted select statement (`SELECT * FROM Test where ID=17179869322`) are both "pure" SQL. The chances are that these will be passed more-or-less directly to the underlying SQLite engine and so would be expected to "work". This is pretty much confirmed by the fact that although the select statement gave the wrong values, it *did* correctly return one row.

The problem is therefore likely to be *either* inherent in the framework (Cordova+plug-in) *or* in the way it is being used (i.e. the way the returned values were being printed).

Given that inspection of the code to print the results showed no problems, the focus centres on the specific plug-in used, and switching to an alternative confirmed that that was the problem.